# Text Box Formatting

Tags: reporting-services

How do I display address values in one row in a Text Box?
Currently values are appear as multiple rows one under another for example:

```
5,Irivine Place
po box 2345
usa
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
5,Irivine Place,po box 2345,usa
```

Comment: Providing the code that you are attempting to fix can go a long way in getting someone to help you.

Comment: Please advise on this . how to print address in single line in text box

Comment: Seems your data comes with html tags. otherwise it won't display like your question. please show us your expression and actual data that comes from SSMS.

Comment: Did you already adjusted your textbox width?

Comment: Yeah I already adjusted the textbox width but it wont works

Comment: @Pedram I am using below expression in ssrs text box          Replace(First(Fields!CompanyAddress.Value, "CustAccountStatementExtDS"),VBCRLF,", ")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your address is one row in the database then linefeeds must also be being stored. You need to replace these with something else -i.e. a ", " e.g.

```
=Replace(Fields!Address.Value,VBCRLF,", ")
```

You would need to get rid of the final ", " in the line so it then becomes:

```
LEFT(Replace(Fields!Address.Value,VBCRLF,", "),LEN(Replace(Fields!Address.Value,VBCRLF,", ")-2)
```

Of course you will need to substitute VBCRLF with whatever linefeed character your database is using.

Comment: @BI DeveloperThanks for the solution , but it wont working .Please advise on this .

Comment: Thanks for all help . I got the solution. I used the replace function  . =Replace(First(Fields!CompanyAddress.Value, "CustAccountStatementExtDS"),chr(10),",") instead of VBCRLF , Chr(10) works i.e. linefeed.

Comment: Eh? I think that's what "Of course you will need to substitute VBCRLF with whatever linefeed character your database is using." means!! In other words I posted the correct solution but you didn't read it :-(

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer is correct can mark it as so please.